# Jira API - START_ARRAY

Tags: rest, jira

Helo guys, sorry for my English =(

I am building a consumer of the jira api and I had the following error "Can not deserialize instance of Jira out of START_ARRAY token"

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "expand": "description,lead,url,projectKeys",
        "self": "http://",
        "id": "10802",
        "key": "TE",
        "name": "TEST TEST",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "http://",
            "24x24": "http://",
            "16x16": "http://",
            "32x32": "http://"
        },
        "projectCategory": {
            "self": "http://",
            "id": "10200",
            "name": "TTTTTT",
            "description": "TTTTTTTT"
        },
        "projectTypeKey": "software"
    },
    {
        "expand": "description,lead,url,projectKeys",
        "self": "http://",
        "id": "10801",
        "key": "TT",
        "name": "TREINAMENTO TESTE",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "http://",
            "24x24": "http://",
            "16x16": "http://",
            "32x32": "http://"
        },
        "projectTypeKey": "business"
    }
]
```

Here's my code.

```
public class Project {
    private String expand;
    private String self;
    private int ID;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private Avatar avatarUrls;
    private ProjectCategory projectCategory;
    private String projectTypeKey;

//get and setter

}

public class Jira {
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;


    public Jira() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(ArrayList<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }
}
public class Application {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();

        //AUTHORIZATION CIT
        header.set("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXX");
        header.set("app_token", "XXXXXXXXX");

        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(header);


       ResponseEntity <Jira> result = restTemplate.exchange("URL",HttpMethod.GET, entity, Jira.class);

       System.out.println(result.getBody().toString());
    }

}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for you. This error appears because Jira API returns a list of objects.
Here is what you should do:

```
ResponseEntity <Jira[]> result = restTemplate.exchange("URL",HttpMethod.GET, entity, Jira[].class);
List<Jira>=Arrays.asList(result.getBody());
```